# Clamd won't start after update

Tags: redhat, clamav, pcre

Since updating clamd to 0.99.2-1.e15 on our RedHat 5 x86_64 system, it has failed to start successfully. The error we get is as follows:

```
LibClamAV Error: cli_pcre_compile: PCRE compilation failed at offset 52: unrecognized character after (?<
LibClamAV Error: cli_pcre_build: failed to build pcre regex
ERROR: Database initialization error: Malformed database [FAILED]
```

Freshclam works fine. I've even removed clamd, clamav-milter, and freshclam, then re-installed them (using "yum install clamd" and "yum install clamav-milter"), but even after running freshclam, I get the same error when trying to start clamd (using service clamd start).

I've been Googling this error and found a Mac OS X with [a similar issue but the patch was not available](http://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-devel/2015-December/000191.html)

Please advise because I'm not sure how to correct this issue. It appears to be something with PCRE, but I'm not sure (we're running pcre.x86_64, version 6.6-9.el5).

Comment: clamav is an EPEL package. Have you [filed a bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Fedora%20EPEL&component=clamav)? Also keep in mind that RHEL 5 support ends March 31 (in 27 days).

Comment: I'm seeing this problem on a CentOS 5 server as of a few hours ago. ClamAV is installed via WHM 56.0 (build 43).

Answer (score 3):

**In summary:**
This temporary workaround from the CentOS 5 CLI (Command Line Interface) got our mail happily flowing again via amavisd-new:

```
sudo sh -c "cat << EOF >> /var/lib/clamav/daily-23161.ign2
Doc.Macro.GenericHeuristic-5901772-0
Doc.Macro.GenericHeuristic-5931846-1
EOF
service clamd restart"
```

**More details:**
The (filename doesn't matter).ign2 whitelists the troublesome entries from the latest daily.cvd
Thanks @Jamen-McGranahan for the OP (Original Post) and @Michael-Hampton for mentioning bug report. Found these resources useful:
[ClamAV Bugzilla: Bug 11800 - 23161 seems to break clamd](https://bugzilla.clamav.net/show_bug.cgi?id=11800)
[Stack Overflow: How do I use sudo to redirect output ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr)
[Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: How to append multiple lines to a file with bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77277/how-to-append-multiple-lines-to-a-file-with-bash)
[amavis](/questions/tagged/amavis)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the daily update.  I restored the daily.cld from a few days ago and it works fine.  I also disabled freshclam for now so it doesn't mess it up again.

Comment: Just ran freshclam and it appears that the updates are now fixed.

Comment: They reversed the PCRE 7+ requirement for the signatures. We can expect this problem to happen again once RHEL/CentOS/CloudLinux 5 reach EOL later this month.